# Printing causes in a visual style exception

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i am using a third party library "DevComponents for WinForm" for visualizing.
This library use the "VisualStyleRenderer" for drawing their controls.

Now it seems some printer drivers, in my case its a kyocera printer, disable the visual style renderer for the current application context. Because if i open a print dialog and close this dialog without printing any document, my application crashes with the following exception:

**"Visual styles related operation resulted in an error because visuals types are currently disabled in the client area"**

Obviously the printer driver itself is responsible for disable the visual style renderer. I don't know why he is doing that.

I have tried to reenable the visual style immediately after closing the print dialog with:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
```

but without success.

Is there someone who got the same error and are there any solutions or workarounds?

Comment: i read somewhere that changing the windows theme could help, dont know if this is true, Right-click on the desktop and select Personalize.
Choose a theme from Basic and High Contrast Themes.
Click Close.

Comment: Printer drivers cause many problems like this, they are shrink-wrapped malware.  Tough business segment, cut-throat competition with $50 price tags, having to survive on consumables.  It doesn't leave enough money to pay a good programmer's salary.  Junk the printer, your time isn't worth $50 dollars.

Comment: @Koen You are right. Changing the theme solve this issue. Responsible are visual style including the glass effect. But it's a customer project. So i can't say to the customer change the theme ;)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

I could fix the problem. I figured out the printer driver changes the "VisualStyleState" value. 
To solve this I easily rechanged the property to the default setting directly after closing the "PrintDialog" with:

```
Application.VisualStyleState = VisualStyles.VisualStyleState.ClientAndNonClientAreasEnabled;
```